# Return Type is not Optional, but asking to unwrap it

Tags: swift

I have a method in ViewModel which is called registerSchool() and return is Bool. When I call this method in ViewController, then it says I need to unwrap it, because it is optional type. I did not mark the return type is optional! Why am I getting this error message?

ViewController -> RegisterViewController

```
var registerVM = RegisterVM()

@IBAction func registerBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
  RegisterServiceManager.allUsers { [weak self] (result) in
   guard let result = result else { return }
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // the following line saying the return is Bool?
    if self?.registerVM.registerSchool() {
    
   }
  }
 }
}
```

ViewModel -> RegisterVM

```
func registerSchool() -> Bool {
 return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Optional chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html). If `self` is Optional, `self?.registerVM.registerSchool()` is Optional.